# Filter table results by filter box input, with Javascript

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I am attempting to filter a table based on the value of an input box.

I have it currently working on the HTML side, like so...

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in model.info | filter:inputFilter" ..... >
    <td> {{ person.name }} </td>
    <td> {{ person.height }} </td>
</tr>

<input class="filterBox" type="text" ng-model="inputFilter">
```

As said before, it works swell. It filters as I type, and is very quick and snappy.

In an effort to make the code reusable, I'd really like to be able to convert this into a Javascript function, but the syntax is escaping me. Yes, I've read the documents, but am not sure how I could just have it update in real time like it does through the HTML side.

Thanks :D

Austin

Comment: This filter works with just two lines of code, how much more re-usable could angulars built in filter functionality be?

Comment: It was more of the desire to see if it was possible to do. But yes, I do agree that it is not as efficient to do something such as that.